# Flutter App with background music (external)

Tags: flutter, dart

When playing music on an app running in the background (ie, Google Play Music, Apple Music, Spotify etc), if you play any audio in your flutter app the background music just stops / pauses and doesn't restart after your audio has completed playing.

I've tried this with the TTS library and the AudioPlayer library on iOS.

Any tips on how to resume playing the background audio after my audio has completed (which is literally just a 2/3 second phrase)?

Not sure yet whether this affects Android.

NOTE: TTS is used in this example but it happens with every library that I've tried.

Pubspec.yaml

```
tts: "^1.0.1"
```

Code:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:tts/tts.dart';

void main() => runApp(new MyApp());

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Flutter Demo',
      theme: ThemeData(
        primarySwatch: Colors.red,
      ),
      home: AudioExample(),
    );
  }
}

class AudioExample extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _AudioExampleState createState() => _AudioExampleState();
}

class _AudioExampleState extends State<AudioExample> {

  speak() async {
    Tts.speak('Hello World');
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text('Audio example app'),
      ),
      body: Container(
        width: double.infinity,
        height: double.infinity,
        decoration: BoxDecoration(
          color: Colors.grey[300],
        ),
        child: Column(
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
          crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
          children: <Widget>[
            IconButton(
              icon: Icon(Icons.play_arrow),
              onPressed: speak,
              color: Colors.red,
              iconSize: 100.0,
            ),
            Padding(
              padding: const EdgeInsets.all(20.0),
              child: Text(
                  'Will say hello world once clicked and pause background audio on iOS - how to restart background audio after playing has finished?',
                textAlign: TextAlign.center,
              ),
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: You should open an issue on the respective plugins.

Answer (score -1):

You Can Add Music In Java File Better Than Flutter and Add Looping Go To android/app/src/main/java/com/example/ProjectName/MainActivity.java

and add

```
  mediaPlayer = MediaPlayer.create(getApplicationContext(), R.raw.MusicName);
  mediaPlayer.setLooping(true);
  mediaPlayer.start();
  mediaPlayer.setLooping(true);
```

in method onCreate and go to folder called res and create in it a folder called raw and put in it your music

Comment: Thanks Karim, my issue is iOS though, haven’t test Android yet. I have cobbled together a fix which works on iOS but it’s buggy (I’m a Java dev, not Obj-C).

Comment: Search in Internet And Get Swift Or Obj-C Script , I Don't Have Any Experience With Java But I Get A Script And Insert It Into Java Class

Comment: @KarimMohamed you really shouldn't be proud of not knowing what you are doing and just copypasting scripts you find out in the wild in the internet....

Comment: I am not proud but it easier than flutter and you must see who is the better to make your property and make it because i shouldn't go to learn a new language for a small thing :D" , In The End The Computer Doesn't Give Interest About Your Language it Give Interest about 0 and 1 .